# Enumerating AD domains with PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, trust

We have a domain with over 80 other "Trusted" domains attached.  This means that some of our groups are cross linked, with users from one domain, in groups on another domain, etc.  I have written a script that creates lists of users from a certain set of groups on one of the domains, but some of them are from other domains so I just get the Foreign Identifier.  I need to link this to the other domains, but I need the SID of each domain.

Is there a PHP equivalent of Win32's *DsEnumerateDomainTrusts*?  I don't want to have to write out all the SIDs by hand, and then keep updating them manually when new domains are added, or old ones are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an LDAP query for [trustedDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects in the System container of the domain.  For me, the domain's sid is in the `securityIdentifier` attribute.

Comment: I used this to grab the securityIdentifier for each domain, but it is returning something like this: ‘wà˜¢4ÝÒÞ¨õ - how can I convert this into the numbers that link to the AD SID?

Comment: @sacredzero It is stored in binary form.  In .NET I read it as a byte array, and use the SecurityIdentifier class to get into the string form.  You can probably Google someone doing this in PHP.

Comment: OK, so I think I have worked it out - for anyone else that may visit this page!  You need to use unpack("H*",$sid) - where $sid are those weird characters.  You then need to follow this to decode it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Machine_SIDs

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to it:

```
function ldap_sidconvert($ldapbytes)
{
    $d_proc=unpack("H*",$ldapbytes);
    $d_proc['hex1']=str_split(substr($d_proc[1],-24),2);
    foreach ($d_proc['hex1'] as $key=>$value)
    {
        $d_proc['hex2'][floor($key/4)][]=$value;
    }
    foreach ($d_proc['hex2'] as $key=>$value)
    {
        $d_proc['hex3'][$key]=hexdec(implode(array_reverse($d_proc['hex2'][$key],FALSE)));
    }
    return implode("-",$d_proc['hex3']);
}
```

And then you can call it by passing the value of the securityidentifier field to it:

```
ldap_sidconvert($domains[0]['securityidentifier'][0])
```

In this example, it is just looking at the first domain in the list, replace the first 0 with 1,2,3... etc as required.  This only converts the last 24 hex digits, I am not sure how to process the first 24, but I believe they are not unique anyway so they shouldn't be required.

This may not be the best way to do it, so I am happy to accept criticism for my coding, but hopefully it will help someone in the future.

This may be a useful reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Machine_SIDs